# View with home button on top

Tags: ios, autolayout

My application has in wAny hAny a view with texts inside and below an image view with graphic. I've modified the constraints with wAny hCompact so that when I rotate the iphone (landscape mode) I get now side by side the view (1/3 of the width) and the image view (.6 of the width and .7 of the height).

All works fine except when I rotate 2 times (with the simulator) so that I am now in portrait mode the home button on top. The simulator displays as if I was in landscape mode: the view on top but the text vertical and the image view below but the graphic loads as if I was in landscape mode.

Any ideas how to fix that? Is it a simulator issue?

Comment: Attach screen shots of portrait and landscape to get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cmd-> > to change mode with the simulator.

1. portrait mode:

[image]

2. landscape mode:

[image]

3. back in portrait mode - home button on top (I think):

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're not supporting Upside down portrait orientation.

In XCode, click on your project, then on your target and tick the Device Orientation checkboxes you want under Deployment Info.

[image]

Comment: If I select Portrait/Upside-down it doesn't do the rotation in landscape mode correctly. It just does the rotation keeping the portrait mode. If I add the landscape ticks, I still have the same problem. It's not a major issue but annoying. It does not make sense to use the phone in portrait mode the home button at the top.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to not use the Upside Down orientation, I don't think anyone will complain about that ever.